# Difficulty in detected ellipses in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am trying to detect ellipses in some images.
After some functions I got this edges map:

[image: edge map]

I tried using Hough transform to detect ellipses, but this transform has very high complexity, so my computer didn't finish running the transform command even after 5 hours(!).

I also tried doing connected components and got this:

[image: connected components]

In last case I also tried continue and binarized the image.

In all cases I am stuck in these steps, and have no idea how continue from here.

My mission is detect tomatoes in the image. I am approaching this by trying to detect circles and ellipses and find the radius (or average radius in ellipses case) for each one.

edited:

I add my code for the first method (the result is edge map from above):

```
img = cv2.imread(r'../images/assorted_tomatoes.jpg')

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

imgAfterLight=lightreduce(img)
imgAfterGamma=gamma_correctiom(imgAfterLight,0.8)

th2 = 255 - cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgAfterGamma,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,5,3)
median2 = cv2.medianBlur(th2,3)
```

where median2 is the result of shown above in edge map

and the code for connected components:

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

fname=r'../images/assorted_tomatoes.jpg'
blur_radius = 1.0
threshold = 50

img = scipy.misc.imread(fname) # gray-scale image
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(img.shape)

# smooth the image (to remove small objects)
imgf = ndimage.gaussian_filter(gray_img, blur_radius)
threshold = 80

# find connected components
labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(imgf > threshold)
```

where labeled is the result above

another edit:

this is the input image:

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrAf8.jpg)

The problem is that after edge detection, there are a lot of unnecessary edges in sub regions that disturbing for make smooth edge map

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: you really need to provide a [mcve] (I would definately upvote this if you had that)

Comment: You probably need to stake a step back and re-visit your edge map. I can't give you advice on how to improve it, because I don't know what you input image looks like, but think about this: as soon as you binarize your image, you throw away a lot of information; you need to make sure that the binarized image contains all the information you need for subsequent steps. In this case, I have a hard time counting tomatoes in that edge map, so you've thrown away important information!

Comment: I edit and add the input image. My problem is when i execute edge detector, i get a lot of unnecessary edges  that disturb to make clearly edge map

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like a classic problem for the watershed algorithm. It is designed for segmenting out touching objects like the tomatoes. My example is in Matlab (I'm on the wrong computer today) but it should translate to python easily. First convert to greyscale as you do and then invert the images

```
 I=rgb2gray(img)
 I2=imcomplement(I)
```

The image as is will over segment, so we remove minima that are too shallow. This can be done with the h-minima transform

```
I3=imhmin(I2,50);
```

You might need to play with the 50 value which is the height threshold for suppressing shallow minima. Now run the watershed algorithm and we get the following result.

```
L=watershed(I3);
```

[image: Watershed output]
The results are not perfect. It needs additional logic to remove some of the small regions, but it will give a reasonable estimate. The watershed and h-minima are contained in the skimage.morphology package in python.

Comment: i will be very happy if you will able to upload your example. Meanwhile i succeed detect 40 tomatoes+2 false positive detection. in addition, not all  detected tomatoes encircled by circle in appropriate size, so my approach is limited and has big tradeoff between circle amount and circle appropriate size